# Consider the number of $3$ distinct numbers formed with the digits $2,3,5,8,9$. How many of them are even?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to answer the following:

> Consider the number of $3$ distinct numbers formed with the digits $2,3,5,8,9$. How many of them are even?

I first tried to make the following counting: First choose one of the even digits for the end, that's two choices. Then choose the rest of them at will. This yields $2*3*2=12$. But the answer is not $12$, it need to be made like: $1*4*3+1*4*3=24$. I don't get what is wrong with the first counting, can you help me?

Comment: Can there be repeat digits?

Comment: @daOnlyBG No. Distinct digits.

Answer (score 4):

Well you start from the last digit so there are 2 ways to choose it, but you only used one of them so you have 4 numbers left. So you can just do 4 times 3 for the remaining digits. So you would get 4*3*2 which is 24.

Answer (score 2):

The ones digit can have one of two options; the tens digit can have one of four, and the hundreds digit can have one of three:

$$2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 = 24$$ different possibilities.

The reason your original reasoning didn't work out is when you assigned two different possibilities to the ones digit, and then discounted the fact that the other of $\{2,8\}$ that you didn't select for the ones digit can still be in the tens digit. Once you fix that issue, it should be easy to see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only 2 digits that make it even are 2 and 8.

Case 1 (2):

There are 2 digits that can be changed, choosing from the set {3,5,8,9}

Therefore the probability is $_4P_2=12.$

Case 2 (8):

There are 2 digits that can be changed, choosing from the set {3,5,2,9}

Therefore the probability is $_4P_2=12.$

The number of successful cases is 12+12=24.

Comment: It is not combination because order would change the number for example 358 and 538.

Comment: Thanks, fixed my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{2}{1}$ ways to select the last digit out of the numbers $2$ and $8$, and $\binom{4}{2}2!$ ways to select and to permute the remaining $2$ digits out of the remaining $4$ digits available. Hence,

$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{2}2! = 24$$